# Iterate through an stl container in c++?

Tags: c++, list, vector, stl

I am having trouble iterating through a template that could have any number of data structures(list,vector,etc)

With the given template is there a surefire way to iterate through this? I am having trouble with declaring a type and yes I have tried "auto" and "auto&" which dont seem to work at all. Thanks for pointers.

```
template<typename ElementType, typename ContainerType> 
ElementType findMax(ContainerType& container) {
for (typeid(container).name i = container.begin(); i !=container.end(); ++i){
    cout << i;
}
return 10;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? What's wrong with `auto`? What _didn't work at all_? Why do you need `type`?

Comment: Why 'auto' is not working for you?

Comment: 'ElementType' and 'ContainerType'. Are those valid types? It's not clear if they are. They do not match the spelling in your template.

Comment: First error is : error: 'i' does not contain a type. If I use auto

Comment: Are you compiling with C++11?

Comment: No, do I have to?

Comment: Yes. `auto` wasn't added until C++11

Comment: Any way to do it without c++11? I am using online compilers I havent been able to run it on there

Comment: Doing it in a language that's 10 years old will require you to be a bit more specific in your question. Namely mention that you aren't able to use C++11, and perhaps even tag it with [tag:C++03] instead?

Comment: Found an IDE online where it works thanks though Tas

Comment: .name is just a string!

Comment: Why not just use [`std::max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) from the calling code and make this entire function pointless?

Answer (score 2):

Just let it be automatic.

```
for (auto i = container.begin(); i != container.end(); ++i)
```

If you are not available with C++11, you can use typedefs in container.

```
for (typename ContainerType::iterator i = container.begin(); i != container.end(); ++i)
```

Notice that the code doesn't care the case that `ContainerType` is an array.

Also, I think you want to print the content of container, not iterator itself.

```
    cout << *i;
```

[(live example)](http://ideone.com/xMAlAQ)

Comment: Well I am first just trying to print out what ever structure came in and the I could return something other than an int. I do get error :  'i' does not contain a type. -With that code

Comment: @LearningLaw I edited, but the loop is not changed. it works - see the live example.

Comment: Thanks that IDE is just what I need, I can work with that thx @ikh

Comment: You'll need a `typename` before `ContainerType::iterator`.